# How to use 2 for loop select statements in pl/sql block?

Tags: oracle, plsql

We have referred below link with similar issue but still not able to get desired output,

[How to use a variable from a cursor in the select statement of another cursor in pl/sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072992/how-to-use-a-variable-from-a-cursor-in-the-select-statement-of-another-cursor-in/51702204#51702204)

```
**PL/SQL Block:**

begin
  for d in (select listagg(''''||deptno||'''',',')
               within group(order by deptno) deptno  from dept)
  loop
       for e in (select * from emp where deptno=d.deptno)
       loop
            dbms_output.put_line( 'Employee ' || e.ename ||
                                ' in department ' || d.dname );
       end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

We are not able to generate message with above pl/sql block.

Comment: If you run the first cursor query on its own you'll see a *single string value* of a comma-seperated list. No employee matches that *entire* single string. Why do you want to use multiple loops? Or PL/SQL at all?

Comment: how Looks you data in a table? what is expected Output?

Comment: yes, there are multiple dept no but we need to check from comma separated string, if there is at least 1 dept no is matched with dept no in emp table then it should display corresponding emp no and dept no.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need to check from a comma separated string when you have the original values available?

Comment: Thanks a lot..got your point which resolve my issue as well.

Comment: Just stumbled over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073212/266304) which looks remarkably like what you are trying to do.